# Strip Quote from key Using DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I am currently reading data out from a csv files, and i wanted to turn it into a dictionary, Key Value Pair.

I was able to do that using csv.DictReader. But is there anyway to strip the quotes from the keys?

I have it print out like this

```
{'COUNTRY': 'Germany', 'price': '49', 'currency': 'EUR', 'ID': '1', 'CITY': 'Munich'}
{'COUNTRY': 'United Kingdom', 'price': '40', 'currency': 'GBP', 'ID': '2', 'CITY': 'London'}
{'COUNTRY': 'United Kingdom', 'price': '40', 'currency': 'GBP', 'ID': '3', 'CITY': 'Liverpool'}
```

is there anyway to make it look like this

```
{COUNTRY: 'Germany', price: '49', currency: 'EUR', ID: '1', CITY: 'Munich'}
{COUNTRY: 'United Kingdom', price: '40', currency: 'GBP', ID: '2', CITY: 'London'}
{COUNTRY: 'United Kingdom', price: '40', currency: 'GBP', ID: '3', CITY: 'Liverpool'}


import csv
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("201611022225.csv"))

for row in input_file:
    print row
```

Comment: It looks to me you want to print a JSON. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but every piece of code i have tried returns the key in ' ' or " ".

Comment: Can you show the code fragment that produces the first output?

Comment: Just did that, edited the initial post itself.

Comment: why do you want to print invalid json?

Answer (score 0):

Python uses quotes to indicate that it is a string object when printing. In your case, the dictionary uses string as keys, so when you print, it shows the quotes. But it doesn't actually save the quotes as part of the data, it's just to indicate the data type.

For example, if you write this to a text file and open it later, it will not show you quotes.